# Why doesn't Clang merge these consecutive and adjacent calls to memcpy or memset?

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-optimization, memcpy, memset

When compiling this with Clang 10.0.0 and current Clang-trunk it seems to be missing some pretty obvious optimization oppertunities:

```
struct A {
    int x[16] {0}; // Everything zero init by default
    int y[16] {0};
    int z[16] {0};
};

int foo(A* a, A* b); // dummy function in external translation unit
                     // to block any constant folding and unused variable
                     // elimination, etc.

int func() {

    A a[1024],b[1024]; // clang calls memset for each of a and b
                       // could be optimized to single call

    foo(a,b);

    for( int i = 0 ; i < 1024 ; i++ ) {
        a[i] = b[i]; // clang calls memcpy here 1024 times with
                     // consecutive addresses, could be optimized
                     // to single call.
    }

    return foo(a,b);
}
```

The output generated by Clang for x64 at -O3 is as follows:  https://godbolt.org/z/taKi4G

```
func():                               # @func()
        push    r15
        push    r14
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 393216
        lea     r14, [rsp + 196608]
        xor     ebx, ebx
        mov     edx, 196608
        mov     rdi, r14
        xor     esi, esi
        call    memset
        mov     r15, rsp
        mov     edx, 196608
        mov     rdi, r15
        xor     esi, esi
        call    memset
        mov     rdi, r14
        mov     rsi, r15
        call    foo(A*, A*)
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        lea     rdi, [rsp + rbx]
        add     rdi, 196608
        lea     rsi, [rsp + rbx]
        mov     edx, 192
        call    memcpy
        lea     rdi, [rsp + rbx]
        add     rdi, 196800
        lea     rsi, [rsp + rbx]
        add     rsi, 192
        mov     edx, 192
        call    memcpy
        add     rbx, 384
        cmp     rbx, 196608
        jne     .LBB0_1
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 196608]
        mov     rsi, rsp
        call    foo(A*, A*)
        add     rsp, 393216
        pop     rbx
        pop     r14
        pop     r15
        ret
```

I think that the two calls to memset could be merged into a single memset and the 1024 calls to memcpy could be merged, leaving a single memset and a single memcpy. The memset improvement might be marginal, but I'm pretty sure a single call to memcpy would be significantly faster.

I was trying to convince someone that they *shouldn't* need to use mempcy and memset in their code to copy and zero init arrays of POD structs and should just use constructors and let the compiler handle it. My argument somehwat fell apart when I actually looked at what clang had generated.

Is doing this merging somehow not valid or is clang just missing a trick?

Edit: I checked against GCC 10, and it seems to do the large mempcy as I expected, but still doesn't merge the memsets.

Comment: I would not implement this optimization either, it is simply not worth the effort. The overhead of setting up the parameters and performing the call is negligable compared to the cost of the  memset/memcpy operation itself.

Comment: I've updated my question with a more compelling example.

Comment: With gcc I do see a single large memcpy. bugs.llvm.org is where bugs, enhancement requests, etc should be filed, not stackoverflow.

Comment: I get a single call to `mempy` when using `std::copy`: https://godbolt.org/z/H3DsN9